# How to make Dropdown menu using :hover on <a> in place of hover on <ul>?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, internet-explorer-6

IE 6 only support :Hover on `<a>` then can we make css drop down using :hover on `<a>`

http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

This example use JavaScript to add hover on LI

> 'sfhover' class to li elements in the
>   'nav' id'd ul element when they are
>   'moused over' and removes it, using a
>   regular expression, when 'moused out'.
>
> So now we've got the Suckerfish
>   pumping out new classes, the next step
>   is to simply duplicate the :hover
>   selector with 'sfhover' class
>   selectors:

Comment: Can you rephrase this? I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify your position on javascript and perhaps explain your reasons for avoiding a javascript solution?

Comment: Also, IE6 doesn't apply the :hover attributes to elements within an <a> anchor tag. So, if you had <a><span/></span>, IE6 won't obey the CSS style for a:hover span{}

Answer (score 2):

You can *sort of* make it work.  The code below displays a functional menu that relies on `a:hover` to trigger display.  However, it comes with a few caveats:

- Since you can't nest `<a />` tags in [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2) or [XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions), you're limited to a single level of menu items.
- For the same reason, you have to use JavaScript `onclick` event handlers to handle user clicks on menu items.
- IE6 seems to require a `:hover` rule on the anchor tag itself in order to trigger hover behavior.  Without the `#menu:hover` rule, the `#menu:hover span` was ignored.  The rule needs to have at least one style assignment in it, and not all properties seem to work (e.g. `background-color` or `border` worked, but `color` didn't).

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CSS Menu in IE6</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #menu {
            background-color: #cccccc;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            position: relative;
        }

        #menu span {
            display: none;
        }

        /* I'm using <b /> tags for the submenu items, just to make the styling easier. */
        #menu span b {
            display: block;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        /* IE6 seems to require some :hover rule on the anchor element itself.
           Without it, the '#menu:hover span' rule below is ignored. */
        #menu:hover {
            border: none;
        }

        #menu:hover span {
            background-color: #cccccc;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 1em;
            left: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="#" id="menu">Menu
            <span>
                <b onclick="alert('Item 1!');">Item 1</b>
                <b onclick="alert('Item 2!');">Item 2</b>
                <b onclick="alert('Item 3!');">Item 3</b>
            </span>
        </a>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum doler sit amet...
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**:
IE6 does sort of work with nested `<a />` elements.  I tried embedding a link within a submenu, and it displayed properly but mousing over the inner link caused the outer link to lose `:hover`, and the menu would disappear out from under the cursor.

However,  apparently if you wrap the menu in a table (as demonstrated [here](http://www.grc.com/menu2/invitro.htm)), it will work.  Note that the below code works, but won't validate and might blow up in other browsers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CSS Menu in IE6</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #menu {
            background-color: #cccccc;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #menu ul {
            display: none;
        }

        #menu:hover {
            border: none;
        }

        #menu:hover ul {
            background-color: #cccccc;
            display: block;
            margin: 0;
            margin-left: 10px;
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="#" id="menu">Menu
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </a>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum doler sit amet...
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: then how this menu is working fine in IE6 without js http://www.grc.com/menu2/invitro.htm

Comment: @Jitendra, why are you still asking the question while you are linking to solutions that fit your constriants?

Comment: Ah, clever.  I saw that IE would display a nested link properly, but it wasn't playing nice with `:hover`.  Apparently wrapping the menu in a table fixes that.  Horribly non-standard, but if you don't care about validation then I guess it will work.  My answer has been updated with an explanation and example.

Comment: It's also worth noting the tricky conditional comment usage on that page.  They've structured them such that IE6 will see the table-wrapped `<ul />` inside the top-level menu anchor element, but all other browsers will see an unwrapped `<ul />` *next to* the anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).

If javascript is absolutely not an option, you can use one of the many examples of CSS only dropdown menus, such as [The ULTIMATE CSS only drop-down menu](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/final_drop.html) by Stu Nicholls.

In my opinion, making IE6 behave all around via js is preferable to css hacks that have to be implemented for every feature it lacks.

Comment: I don't want to use javascript

Comment: Why are you avoiding javascript?

Comment: if i can make menu without javascript then i would go for it

Comment: Have you examined any of the CSS options out there, such as the one I linked to above?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can as long as you nest the sub menu within the anchor.

```
<a class="hoverMenu">
  MenuText
  <div class="subMenu">
    SubMenuText
  </div>
</a>

.hoverMenu .subMenu { display: none; }
.hoverMenu:Hover .subMenu { display: block; }
```

I haven't tested this out for IE6, but this is the basic idea behind an all css menu in any other browser.  Not sure if you can nest anchors or not.

Comment: ohh well, funny enough though your link is working great in chrome.